# My music goes from headphones to speakers when the cable is in a weird angle

Tags: audio, headphones, speaker

I have a pair of AKG K371 headphones, and when I twist the cable in a weird way, the music stops on the headphones and plays on the speakerphone, even though the device audio with headphones disconnected is 0.

Is there a way to completely disable the speaker when headphones are connected? I have root and Tasker.

Answer (score 2):

You have a faulty cable. When the audio cuts out in the headphones, the 'phone thinks there is no longer a cable connected. Replacing the cable should fix the problem. Forcing it to always use the headphones won't work if headphones "aren't connected."